# Getting IndexOutOfBoundIndex on removing from string

Tags: android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been at this for long time and still unable to figure out how to remove "id" from my  string.
It adds to the array list using the same method but doesnt remove from the string.
How to remove it?

**travelselectedId.remove(tv.getId());**

Please be kind enough to also explain why is this IndexOutOfBoundIndex error being thrown. I know its something to do with my getId() method but am unable to figure out the exact reason.

```
 for(int i=1;i<=activityList.size();i++)
        {
            final TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setId(Integer.parseInt(activityList.get(i-1).get(Table.user_travelactivities.id.toString())));
            tv.setText(activityList.get(i-1).get(Table.user_travelactivities.travelactivity.toString()));
            if(!travelselectedId.contains(tv.getId()))
            {
                
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_rect_shape);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.plus_profile,0, 0, 0);
            tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.tripoto_orange));
            }
            else
            {
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_filled_rect_shape);
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check,0,0,0);
                tv.setTextColor(NewProfileSettings.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
            tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
            tv.setTextSize(16f);                
            FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        
            
        
            params.horizontal_spacing=14;
            params.vertical_spacing=14;
            x1.addView(tv,params);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                    
                    if (travelselectedId.contains(tv.getId())) {    
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_rect_shape);
                        tv.setTextColor(NewProfileSettings.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.tripoto_orange));
                        travelselectedId.remove(tv.getId());// ================= THIS LINE WHAT SHOULD I DO
                        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.plus_profile,0, 0, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_filled_rect_shape);
                        tv.setTextColor(NewProfileSettings.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        
                        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.check,0,0,0);
                        travelselectedId.add(tv.getId());
                    }
                    
                }
            });
            
                
        }
    }
```

Comment: `int i=1` Without looking any further, you probably want `int i=0`. Or the more daring `i<=activityList.size()+1;`

Comment: That wont help. I've edited the question.

Comment: Try `travelselectedId.remove(v.getId());`

Answer (score 0):

*I assume that `travelselectedId` is a [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of some sort (e.g., an `ArrayList`).*

You are using the wrong version of `List.remove()`. That is, you are calling [List.remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) -- which removes the item with the specified list index. Instead, you should be calling [List.remove(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) -- which will remove the Object in the list with that value.

Try the following, which will call the latter version of `remove()`:

```
travelselectedId.remove(Integer.valueOf(tv.getId()));
```

Comment: When i try removing all the elements from the list all are not being removed